# Error 119 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Tags: c#

Whats the Problem With My code

```
(String.Compare(Reader["Uname"].ToString(), user.ToString()) 
&& String.Compare(Reader["Pname"].ToString(), pass.ToString()))
```

Comment: The error message says it precisely.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use String.Equals:

```
(String.Equals(Reader["Uname"].ToString(), user.ToString()) 
&& String.Equals(Reader["Pname"].ToString(), pass.ToString()))
```

String.Compare returns if one is greater than the other (1 / -1) for sorting, or 0 if they are Equal.

Answer (score 1):

[String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/system.string.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) compares two specified `String` objects and returns an **integer** that indicates their relative position in the sort order.

So it returns `int` not `bool` as you may expect. And `&&` operator cannot be applied to `int`, only to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Just what the error message says. String.Compare() returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on the sort order of the compared strings. The '&&'operator is reserved to boolean values, and C# does cannot convert boolean to integer or vice versa.